# Error: relativeSourceLocation is not a valid Plugin property React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhuck.png

[] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF8HT.png)

I want to use react-native reanimated for my project.
I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the react-native-reanimated/plugin to your project you may encounter a false-positive "Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet" error. In most cases, this can be fixed by cleaning the application's cache. Depending on your workflow or favourite package manager that could be done by:

```
yarn start --reset-cache
npm start -- --reset-cache
expo start -c
```

or other.